# Visualize networkx using vis.js

Tags: python, json, networkx, vis.js

I am using the `Python` library `networkx` to create a directed graph with almost 2k nodes, and I want to visualize the graph using  `vis.js` library

I know how to export it as Json, but I am not able to generate a compatible format to use it directly into vis.js

I should have a json String output that looks like:

**nodes:**

```
[
  {id: 1, label: 'a'},
  {id: 2, label: 'b'},
  {id: 3, label: 'c'}
]
```

**edges:**

```
[
    {from: 1, to: 2, label: 'label1'},
    {from: 1, to: 3, label: 'label2'},
    {from: 2, to: 4, label: 'label3'},
    {from: 2, to: 5, label: 'label3'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `viz.js` but if it's not a hard requirement I suggest you export your graph to [GEXF](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html#networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf):

```
G = nx.path_graph(4)  # your graph here
nx.write_gexf(G, "test.gexf")
```

And then import it into [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org), a dedicated high performance graph drawing library, using [the dedicated GEXF importer plugin](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/load-external-gexf.html).

Comment: i did try `sigma.js` but it doesn't show nodes attributes, so i'ts not that useful for my use case becouse my graph has in id and a liste of attributes that must be shown on hover

Comment: Of course you can show attributes on hover in Sigma. Check this example https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/events.html

Answer (score 0):

There is port to `Jupyter` of `visJS`. you can find it [here](https://github.com/ucsd-ccbb/visJS2jupyter).

The package is in `Python 2` but the porting to `Python 3` has started.

Please note that as mentioned, it only works with `Jupyter` (which is great, if you ask me!).